# How to open more than 16k connections on Windows with ws

Tags: node.js, windows

Faced with some windows restriction or something. Node.js with ws module can't handle more than 16k socket connections. Over this amount sockets just start disconnecting. Had similar problem on Ubuntu, but after increasing ulimit everything is ok. Should I increase some parameters on windows? (windows 10, not server, home PC). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the uws module, it uses a C++ binding so that might change stuff